# Scala : how to pass variable in a UDF and use in withColumn

Tags: scala

I have a variable of type Map[String, Set[String]

```
val metadata = Map(a -> Set(b ,c))

val colToUse = "existingcol"  // Option[String]
```

I am trying to add a new column in my dataFrame using metadata and colToUse which is an  existing column in my dataframe

value of metadata is Set of Strings and
key is just a string which is a value of a column in df.

eg :

```
val metadata = Map['mike', ['physics','chemistry']] 

val colToUse = 'student_name' // student_name is a column name in df
```

'mike' will be a value of "student_name" column.

i am trying to add a new column in existing DF where i can add subjects of each student based on student_name and metadata

```
myDF.withColumn("subjects", metadata.getorelse(col(colToUse), set.empty)
```

The above will not work in scala as i need pass columns only in withColumn.

Tried using UDF

```
def logic: (Map[String, Set[String]], String) => Set[String] =
  (metadata: Map[String, Set[String]], colToUse: String) => {
    metadata.getOrElse(colToUse, Set("a"))
  }

def myUDF = udf(logic)

def getVal: Column = { myUDF(metadata, col(colToUse.get) }
```

and using it in withcolumn :

```
myDF.withColumn("newCol", getVal(metadata, colToUse)
```

Getting error :  Unsupported literal type class scala.Tuple2

Looking for a best simplistic way to approach this ?

Issue 2: In getVal , for passing metadata a column is expected but i am passing a map

Comment: What is the value of the metadata Map. The key is the name of a column, but the values?

Comment: value of metadata is Set of Strings and key is just a string which is value of a column in df

Comment: value of metadata is Set of Strings and key is just a string which is a value of a column in df.
eg :val metadata =  Map['mike', ['physics','chemistry']]
val colToUse = 'student_name' // student_name is a column name in df

'mike' will be a value of "student_name" column.

i am trying to add a new column in existing DF where i can add subjects of each student based on student_name and metadata




myDF.withColumn("subjects", metadata.getorelse(col(colToUse), set.empty)

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this is what you need:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[1]").getOrCreate()

val df = spark.createDataFrame(
  spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(Row("mike"))),
  StructType(List(StructField("student_name", StringType)))
)

df.show()
```

First test dataframe:

```
+------------+
|student_name|
+------------+
|        mike|
+------------+
```

And now, create the udf that uses the map:

```
val metadata = Map("mike" -> Set("physics", "chemistry"))
val colToUse = "student_name"

def createUdf =
   udf((key: String) => metadata.getOrElse(key, Set.empty))
```

and uset it in withColumn function:

```
df.withColumn("subjects", createUdf(col(colToUse))).show()
```

it gives:

```
+------------+--------------------+
|student_name|            subjects|
+------------+--------------------+
|        mike|[physics, chemistry]|
+------------+--------------------+
```

am I missing something?

Comment: Issue i am getting with this approach is :  col(colToUse.get) is not able to get value from the column student_name , it is passing column name in the createUDF

Comment: Using createUDF is giving this error while i am trying to write the rows :
Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$createUdf$1$1: (string) => array<string>)
It is supposed to return Set<string>

Comment: col(colToUse.get) is the name of the column, and the .get comes from the Option [T] type. The values come once spark is traversing the df, for each row the value of the column is pushed onto the udf.